# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, apache-poi

```
    XSSFWorkbook workbook=new XSSFWorkbook("C:\\Users\\Ramesh\\Downloads\\selenium-2.53.1\\Excel files\\OceanRates per MonthTest cases.xlsx");

    XSSFSheet sheet= (XSSFSheet) workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
    XSSFRow row= sheet.getRow(2);
    String val=row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
    System.out.println(val);
```

I had above program, and when trying to execute, I'm getting "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject".

I have added Apache POI jar file in IntelliJ.

Comment: @hiten - that version is ancient (and a beta version) - POI latest release is 4.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Include following jar and try.

> xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar

Comment: Could you use the up to date xmlbeans jar (3.0.1)?